# How can i go to Bookmarked page in react?

Tags: reactjs

```
Enabled in react index.html

<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer-when-downgrade" /> 

post that in header referer is visible, as below

referer: https://localhost:3000/search
```

I have tried to get the value in of referer in react using `document.referrer` but i get '' (empty)

I was expecting to get https://localhost:3000/search as values of document.referrer.

Dot.Net Core + React js is my tech stack

Comment: what is the reason you need the previous URL? is it for navigation? if so you can use History to go back

Comment: my use case is as follow:
Lets say i bookmark https://localhost:3000/search and
later when i want to got to this page ,then it first goes to Login page https://localhost:3000/login and then to default landing page of the website say https://localhost:3000/landingPage. But in this scenario i have to go to https://localhost:3000/search url after login

2nd Use Case
Lets say i give a static url to external website say on facebook. When people use the link https://xyx:3000/search in this case as well post login i want to users to land on https://xyx:3000/search instead of default landing page

Comment: i have edited the subject , apologies of having previous URL in subjectline